# How to create MUC in gtalk using python xmpppy

Tags: python, xmpp, chat, chatroom, xmpppy

Can anybody help me to fix this code, I really need it, but have no idea what to do next. I need to create a groupchat and send messega to invited persons, now it is example2@gmail.com, but it does not...
Is there mistake?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,os,xmpp,time                                          
jid = 'example1@gmail.com'
psw = 'psw'
jid=xmpp.protocol.JID(jid)
cl=xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(),debug=[])
cl.connect()
cl.auth(jid.getNode(),psw)
node = jid.getNode()
domain = 'talk.google.com'
room = node + '@' + domain
nroom = room + '/' + 'Maria'
mes = xmpp.Presence(to=nroom) 
cl.sendInitPresence()
cl.send(mes)


NS_MUCUSER = 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'
invite = xmpp.simplexml.Node('invite')
invite.setAttr('to', 'example2@gmail.com')
invite.setTagData('reason', 'I really need it!') 
mess = xmpp.Message(to=room)
mess.setTag('x', namespace=NS_MUCUSER).addChild(node=invite)
cl.send(mess)


msg = xmpp.protocol.Message(body="Hello there!")
msg.setTo(room)
msg.setType('groupchat')
cl.send(msg)
time.sleep(1)   # some older servers will not send the message if you disconnect immediately after sending
cl.disconnect()
print "Done"
```

Comment: Hi Maria, you will get more and better quality answers if you show what you have done so far - Some snippets of code demonstrating where you are confused.

Comment: I know there are mistakes here, but it all I could do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my mistake. Problem is that I didn't wait enough to get answer from the server and I invited people before server was able to create a chat room. Now I wait until I get answer from server and then send invite message.

Answer (score 0):

According to the specs - http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#createroom - sending a  request to join a room that doesn't exist should create that room (or MUC)

> The workflow for creating and configuring such rooms is as follows:
>
> ```
> The user sends presence to <room@service/nick> and signal his or her support
> for the Multi-User Chat protocol by including extended presence information 
> in an empty <x/> child element qualified by the 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc' 
> namespace (note the lack of an '#owner' or '#user' fragment).
>
> If this user is allowed to create a room and the room does not yet exist, the
> service MUST create the room according to some default configuration, assign the
> requesting user as the initial room owner, and add the owner to the room but not 
> allow anyone else to enter the room (effectively "locking" the room). The initial
> presence stanza received by the owner from the room MUST include extended 
> presence information indicating the user's status as an owner and acknowledging
> that the room has been created (via status code 201) and is awaiting 
> configuration.
> ```

So something like this is *supposed* to work according to the documentation.

```
jid=xmpp.protocol.JID('example@gmail.com')
cl=xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(),debug=[])

jid = xmpp.protocol.JID('example@gmail.com')
client = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=[])
client.connect()
client.auth(jid.getNode(), 'my secret password')
client.send(xmpp.Presence(to='room@talk.google.com/ANick')
```

Comment: I don't understand how to get my room name. How will I send messages to everyone? Should I invite them first? Should they be from my roster? Can you give me example to what 'My Room/My Nick' can be replaced?

Comment: You might want to wade through the specs here: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html